# Get a Fixed sized GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, size, jbutton

I need to make a fixed sized for a GridLayout with 100 buttons located in the center portion of a BorderLayout. On the east portion of the border layout is another Gridlayout that keeps shrinking the center component whenever the text is longer then the size of the current JTextAreas located in the east. The JFrame is not resizable also.

Is there a way to get a fixed size for the center component while allowing the JTextArea to still expand?

Comment: Show code to better explain what you are trying to do. Take a look at [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I need to make a fixed sized for a GridLayout with 100 buttons located in the center portion of a BorderLayout".

Sorry, but that's not going to work. BorderLayout doesn't work like that. You can nest JPanel containers with different Layout managers to get your desired effect.

> "Gridlayout that keeps shrinking the center component whenever the text is longer then the size of the current JTextAreas located in the east."

You should wrap your text area in a `JScrollPane`, and `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` on you text area.  The last two will set it, so that the line typed wraps when  it is reaching the right edge of the text area. Also If you are setting the size to the text area, don't. Instead, use the following constructor to set its size

```
JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(20, 50);   <--- rows, and character columns
jta.setLineWrap(true);
jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(jta);

container.add(scroll);  <--- make sure you don add jta anywhere else
```

Without more context to your querstion, these are really the only valid suggestions I can make.